# Disappearance of payment module prestashop1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I had installed COD plus (Cash on delivery plus (COD+) v1.5.7 - by PrestaHost.eu), It was working fine but suddenly it got disappeared from the payment page on front end. I did lot of research and found "Disable all overrides" in performance tab. After enabling override the COD plus is visible on front end.

May I know what can be the reason of sudden disappearance of COD plus module from frontend and how can i view the cod plus module without touching any overrides button. As override button is under debug mode section.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason is that you installed another module that override the same class of COD and disabled its normal behavior.

You can see COD module source code at its folder in `shop_root/module`.

Good luck.